# Why Inbox app disturbs while notifications disabled?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sync, email, inbox-by-gmail, usability

I get a notification each time when receiving an email although I disabled all notifications of Inbox. This fact is disturbing because Gmail app gives a notification too about the same event at the same time.

Fig.  1 My settings of Inbox in Setting > Notifications > Apps

[image]

Phone: Oneplus 2
System: CM 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, the **Block all** setting is turned **off**. This means that notifications are **not** blocked from this app, so they'll appear as normal. If you want to disable notifications, change this setting to **on**, or turn off the notifications within the app itself.